# RSelenium findElement works with firefox:2.53.1 but not with firefox:latest

Tags: r, docker, selenium, rselenium, selenium-docker

I run Selenium with docker like this:

`docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1`

and this line `remDr$findElement(using = "class", "percent")` in the following R Script  works fine.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("RSelenium")

# A Selenium server has to be running
# Works with: docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1
# Fails with: docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:latest

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://www.alternabank.ca/everyday-banking/high-interest-esavings")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", "percent")
tmp <- webElem$getElementText()

remDr$close()
```

I kill that container and do: `docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:latest`

And then run the same code again. This results in an error:

```
> webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", "percent")
Error in .self$value[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Why is this? How can I get my old code to work with the latest version of firefox. I need the newer version for some other things to work.

I also see that the name of the linux process changes from "firefox" to "Gecko".

Comment: Is the remote server correctly starting up? Selenium is notoriously hard to exit properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991498/rselenium-server-signals-port-is-already-in-use Could it be a port being already in use?

Comment: I think the Selenium server starts correctly. In switching between the two containers, if I don't kill the old container I get a port in use error so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Have you tried:  `docker run -d -p 4445:4444 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-firefox:latest` ? (giving it some extra RAM)

Comment: I've monitored RAM usage on Digital Ocean and it's OK.

Comment: I updated to latest and it broke my code as well.  Win10 desktop no Digital Ocean and a completely different website.

Comment: shouldn't `webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", "percent")` actually be `webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", value = "percent")`  ?

Comment: @djmonki No difference. "value" is assumed.

Comment: I've been having trouble with :latest as well.  Mine works with version 3, but not 4.  So try, `selenium/standalone-firefox:3.141.59-20210929`

Answer (score 1):

When you start the Selenium [docker](/questions/tagged/docker) using the command:

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1
```

Effectively, *`selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0`* uses:

- The legacy Firefox browser and the version was between *Firefox 45.x* to *Firefox 47.x*
- If you have configured the docker container yourself, you are able to specify your own `FIREFOX_VERSION` while building it.
- [Marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530302/how-can-geckodriver-firefox-work-without-marionette-running-python-selenium-3/44537094#44537094) based [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) wasn't mandatory.

So, there's no issue in program execution.

---

But when you start the Selenium [docker](/questions/tagged/docker) using the command:

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:latest
```

[Marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421828/marionette-warn-tls-certificate-errors-will-be-ignored-for-this-session-warning/59427460#59427460) based [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453) comes into play.

There are quite significant updates/modifications/changes between how the *Legacy Firefox Browser* was earlier run and how the *GeckoDriver* currently drives the [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) browser now.

This should also explain why you *see that the name of the linux process changes from "firefox" to "Gecko"*

Additionally, you need to keep the *GeckoDriver* synchronized with the *Firefox Browser* and you can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Selenium: How selenium identifies elements visible or not? Is is possible that it is loaded in DOM but not rendered on UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165)

---

### TL; DR

[StandaloneFirefox 2.53.0 image hosted on hub.docker.com was updated and broke internal build](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/293)