# What are the steps required to get geckodriver working with RSelenium on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, geckodriver, rselenium

This is a follow up to an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69716498/rselenium-findelement-works-with-firefox2-53-1-but-not-with-firefoxlatest) which provided an explanation as to why an older version of Firefox would work with RSelenium (v1.77) `selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1` whereas a newer version breaks, `selenium/standalone-firefox:latest`.

My understanding is that the solution lies in getting the correct version of GeckoDriver.

Looking [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.30.0) and following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870530/how-to-install-geckodriver-in-ubuntu) instructions I now have geckodriver living at /usr/local/bin/

However my script still fails at `webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", "percent")` with the error

`Error in .self$value[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`.

What further steps are required to get RSelenium working with selenium/standalone-firefox:latest?

R Script from earlier question

```
library("tidyverse")
library("RSelenium")

# A Selenium server has to be running
# Works with: docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1
# Fails with: docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:latest

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://www.alternabank.ca/everyday-banking/high-interest-esavings")
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", "percent")
tmp <- webElem$getElementText()

remDr$close()
```

Comment: Are you able to navigate to the webpage?

Comment: remDr$getStatus() after remDr$open() is a populated list. Status after remDr$navigate is `list()`. So I think no.

Comment: try these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395849/cant-execute-rsdriver-connection-refused https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468831/how-to-set-up-rselenium-for-r

Comment: I'm not sure those sites are relevant to my issue.  selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1 works fine. Thus, I think it's a geckodriver issue.